# Getting Two Vertical Scroll Bars in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a div, with id = hbox, which contains multiple divs with *display: inline-block;* 
This hbox works fine in Mozilla Firefox and Google chrome. But in Internet Explorer its showing an additional Vertical Scroll Bar at the right hand side.
[**CLICK HERE FOR DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0nx4eg0g/)

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Horizontal Box</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .hbox {
                overflow: auto;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            .hbox.hcenter {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .hbox > div {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: -4px;
                vertical-align:top;
                text-align: left;
                overflow: auto;   
                white-space: normal;
            }
            .childrenSkyBlue {
                width: 35%;
                background-color: skyblue;
            }
            .childrenOrange {
                width: 35%;
                background-color: orange;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hbox" >
            <div class="childrenSkyBlue" >
                <div>hi</div>
                <input/><br/>
                test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test
                <br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
            </div>
            <div class="childrenOrange" >
                test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test
                test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
            </div>
            <div class="childrenSkyBlue" >
                test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test
                test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
            </div>
            <div class="childrenOrange" >
                test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test
                test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
            </div>
            <div class="childrenSkyBlue" >
                test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test
                test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody tell me how to get rid off this additional scroll bar in IE?

**Note**: When I remove **vertical-align:top;** from my styles, then it works fine in IE as well. But that disturbs the layout of hbox.

Comment: Please try without: `.hbox > div { overflow: auto; }`.

Comment: @emmanuel: if height of a children div is very less, say 100px or 200px, then I need a scroll bar to be shown. So, that entry cannot be removed. Moreover, the additional vertical scroll bar is there because of .hbox